# How to use multiple buttons?

Tags: button, onclick

For the following code, the Add button onclick triggers a breakpoint when the button is clicked.  I cannot get the Edit button to trigger a breakpoint when it is clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 <div id="indexContainer"style="display:none">
         <p style="font-size:40px; color:#9b9da0;">Select a server</p>
         <input type="button" value="Add" id="addBtnIcon" onclick="addBtnChange();">
         <input type="button" value="Edit" id="editBtn" onclick="editBtnClick();">
         <input type="button" value="Remove" id="removeBtn" style="padding:20px 20px;"><br>
         <form>
              <p id="serverName" value="Server name here"></p>
              <p id="serverValue" value="Server address here"></p><br>
              <input type="submit" id="saveBtn" value="Save" style="background-color:#9b9da0; padding:20px 140px;" disabled><br>
         </form>
         <div class="description">
              <p id="serverDesc">Description: A description goes here</p>
              <p id="serverSerial">Serial no: The serial number goes here</p>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have your javascript code?

Comment: By the way your div indexContainer is hidden by default, for e.g. purpose I have made it visible

Answer (score 0):

Here is very basic event handeler

```js
function addBtnChange()
{
 console.log("Add button clicked!");
}

function removeBtnClick()
{
 console.log("Remove button clicked!");
}

function editBtnClick()
{
 console.log("Edit button clicked!");
}
```

```html
<div id="indexContainer" >
         <p style="font-size:40px; color:#9b9da0;">Select a server</p>
         <input type="button" value="Add" id="addBtnIcon" onclick="addBtnChange();">
         <input type="button" value="Edit" id="editBtn" onclick="editBtnClick();">
         <input type="button" value="Remove" id="removeBtn" style="padding:20px 20px; " onclick="removeBtnClick()"><br>
         <form>
              <p id="serverName" value="Server name here"></p>
              <p id="serverValue" value="Server address here"></p><br>
              <input type="submit" id="saveBtn" value="Save" style="background-color:#9b9da0; padding:20px 140px;" disabled><br>
         </form>
         <div class="description">
              <p id="serverDesc">Description: A description goes here</p>
              <p id="serverSerial">Serial no: The serial number goes here</p>
         </div>
</div>
```